# How to add header in all pages except first on in `resume.cls` class

Tags: fancyhdr, resume

Please consider this resume template: https://da.overleaf.com/articles/rishi-shahs-resume/vgxvkmxktyxn.
My resume is more or less built this way but I have two pages. I want to add header to the second page (I have two pages). **How Can I add a header using this source code?**

I have tried

```
...
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{My name}
\rhead{Resume}
\cfoot{\thepage}
...
```

But this will generate header both on the first and second page. I want to exclude from the first page. Many similar questions have been answered in here but none of them solves my problem

Comment: Place `\pagestyle{empty}` or `plain` in the start of the document and then `\pagestyle{fancy}` at a place that the second page has already started.

Comment: Set `\pagestyle{fancy}` and then also issue `\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}`.

Comment: @koleygr This solution is presented several times, but the problem is that I have to specify the exact place where the page change occur..

Comment: @Werner thanks, this solved my problem! If you post it as an answer, I can accept and close this question

Comment: @k.dkhk: Done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `\pagestyle{fancy}` to have a `fancy` page style for the entire document, together with `\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}` which will set the first page (at the beginning of the document) to have an `empty` page style.